# Using microservices to create a trigger framework

Tags: trigger, architecture, framework

I recently heard about a trigger framework that's based on the [microservices](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) architecture. I have searched around and nothing useful has come up. Does anybody have any resources to share?

I can picture Process Builder being the entry-point here, but don't know how the rest of it could look like.

Comment: Triggers reflect the domain layer in a [Separation of Concerns pattern](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Separation_of_Concerns) (another Fowler-espoused architecture) -

Comment: If I had more information trust me I would've included them. But this is literally all I have, and I am as curious as everyone who put this on hold to find out how this framework works. @cropredy can you please elaborate further? I apply SOC on a daily basis but what role does it play in a microservice-based trigger framework?

Comment: Can't really comment on micro services viz triggers except one way or another, triggers are tightly bound to Sobject Dml operations so it will be interesting to see how to repurpose into a services-oriented architecture without bastardization.

Comment: @Mossi, if you're attending Dreamforce, looks like you should go to this session which purports to spend 40 minutes talking about the concept.  https://success.salesforce.com/Sessions#/session/a2q3A000000LBRsQAO If you're not going, find someone who did go and, in November or December or so (once videos are up), ask them to log in and visit the link and find a direct link to the video's hosting site that they can share with you (might take some parsing the source code & guessing at the URL).

Comment: This turned out to be a basic trigger framework that uses interfaces to define criteria and actions. I am disappointed.